# Separate calls to Db data in one foreach loop

Tags: php, database, foreach

OK I hope this isn't too specific.  I have a database driven CMS that a coworker uses with many categories in it.  Here's how it echoes some products we have now:

```
$offers = get_offers('category1','none','compare');

  foreach ($offers as $row) {
    $offername = $row['name'];
    $offerlogo = $row['logo'];
    $offera=$row['detailA'];
    $offerb=$row['detailB'];
    $offerc=$row['detailC'];

 echo "you can have $offername, it's logo looks like <img src='$offerlogo'>" it's characteristics are $offera, offerb, offerc, etc";}
```

This works fine.  My the problem is I want to get offera, offerb and offerc from another category, category 2.  I tried going like this:

```
$offers = get_offers('category1','none','compare');

  foreach ($offers as $row) {

    $offername = $row['name'];
    $offerlogo = $row['logo'];

$offers = get_offers('category2','none','compare');

    $offera=$row['detailA'];
    $offerb=$row['detailB'];
    $offerc=$row['detailC'];

echo "you can have $offername, it's logo looks like <img src='$offerlogo'>" it's characteristics are $offera, offerb, offerc, etc";}
```

But of course that doesn't work.  I don't want my coworker to have to go through the CMS and copy all the information over, is there a way to make this work?

Comment: You must first loop through both offers and combine them somehow. Can you post a sample of what the get_offers function returns (with var_dump, so that the keys are also visible)

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want to do, but you are overriding the value of $offers within your foreach loop.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Is the `offers = get_offers('category2'` line inside the `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the ordering of the results from both calls to `get_offers` matches up, I believe this might work for you:

```
$offers['cat1'] = get_offers('category1', 'none', 'compare');
$offers['cat2'] = get_offers('category2', 'none', 'compare');

$numberOfOffers = count($offers['cat1']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfOffers; $i++)
{
    $offername = $offers['cat1'][$i]['name'];
    $offerlogo = $offers['cat1'][$i]['logo'];

    $offera = $offers['cat2'][$i]['detailA'];
    $offerb = $offers['cat2'][$i]['detailB'];
    $offerc = $offers['cat2'][$i]['detailC'];

    echo "you can have $offername, its logo looks like <img src='$offerlogo'> its characteristics are $offera, $offerb, $offerc, etc\n"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ngm. If the categories match up then you could bring the results from the different call with the following:

```
$offersCat1 = get_offers('category1','none','compare');  
$offersCat2 = get_offers('category2','none','compare');  
foreach ($offers as $key=>$row) {  
    $offera=$offersCat2[$key]['detailA'];  
    $offerb=$offersCat2[$key]['detailB'];  
    $offerc=$offersCat2[$key]['detailC'];  
    echo "you can have {$row['name']}, it's logo looks like <img src='{$row['logo']}'> it's characteristics are $offera, offerb, offerc, etc";  
}
```

This example will do the same thing, but you keep it in the foreach loop. By using the $key=>$row you are able to access the key of the array. I also took the liberty to echo your variables directly rather than putting them in variables. If you put {} around an array variable (or class variable) you can use them within an echo, print or <<<. This makes my life easier.

Example: `echo "This variable {$variable['test']}";`